Float variable is not float?
I have code as below:
def  Inficon():
    try:
        with BGP400_RS232("/dev/serial0") as pg:
            while True:
                pressure = pg.get_pressure(PressureGaugeUnit.MBAR)
                print(type(pressure))
                print(pressure)
                time.sleep(0.5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Measurement stopped by user.")
Inficon()

This give output:
s 'float'>
1000.0
s 'float'>
969.95145756
s 'float'>
1000.0

If I make change to:
def  Inficon():
    try:
        with BGP400_RS232("/dev/serial0") as pg:
            while True:
                pressure = pg.get_pressure(PressureGaugeUnit.MBAR)
                print(type(pressure))
                print(round(pressure,1))
                time.sleep(0.5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Measurement stopped by user.")
Inficon()

It gives error like below:
print(round(pressure))
Type Error: type NoneType doesn't define __round__ method

Why I'm getting this error if rounding float variable?
Is it possible float is not real float and getting error?

You haven't included (or allowed us to identify) the most relevant print, namely print(type(pressure)) immediately preceding print(round(pressure)) when it produced the given error. Surely, the print will have been <class 'NoneType'>. Looks like pg.get_pressure will return None in some cases. Either handle the error or check your data and the actual function to see whether None is a sensical return value.

Clearly, get_pressure() returns None in some circumstances

This suggests that pg.get_pressure(PressureGaugeUnit.MBAR) method is returning None at some point.
To handle this, you should check if pressure is None before rounding it. Here is how you can handle this:
def  Inficon():
    try:
        with BGP400_RS232("/dev/serial0") as pg:
            while True:
                pressure = pg.get_pressure(PressureGaugeUnit.MBAR)
                print(type(pressure))
                if pressure is not None:
                    print(round(pressure,1))
                else:
                    print(pressure)  # or another message
                time.sleep(0.5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Measurement stopped by user.")
Inficon()

This way you avoid calling round() on a NoneType object.

That's true. In some scenarios sensor return NONE value. Thank's Mate, your code work perfectly.
